# What is the syntax of the formula argument in R?

Tags: r, formula

In the package `nnet`, the following example is given:

```
# or
ird <- data.frame(rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3]),
        species = factor(c(rep("s",50), rep("c", 50), rep("v", 50))))
ir.nn2 <- nnet(species ~ ., data = ird, subset = samp, size = 2, rang = 0.1,
               decay = 5e-4, maxit = 200)
table(ird$species[-samp], predict(ir.nn2, ird[-samp,], type = "class"))
```

I do not understand how this part works: `species ~ .`, I understand it is some kind of formula that is passed as argument but I do not know where to search for more information about the syntax of formulaes and what the `.` will represent.

Please close this question if it is a duplicate, I could not find the same question.

Comment: `.` represents all the remaining features (columns)

Comment: do you want to add a full answer explaining what the syntax is for a formula in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` represents all the features/columns except the outcome (which is written on the RHS of `~`). More info can be found here `?formula`

Basically, for the `iris3` data set, the formula

```
species ~ .
```

is equivalent to

```
species ~ Sepal L. + Sepal W. + Petal L. + Petal W.
```